# I'm having trouble vertical aligning text with line-height in a position:fixed; container

Tags: android, html, css

I can't get this line-height to vertical center some text across mobile browsers and other weirdness.

On Chrome and Firefox it works fine and is vertical center.

For some reason in this fiddle the exact same code does not v align center in chrome.
http://jsfiddle.net/SEOplay/D6LtM/

If I remove the `position:fixed; left:0; top:0;` from the `#headTitle` it works fine.

On Android Mobile 4.0.4, user agent, mozilla/5.0 it works fine and is vertical center.

On Android Tablet 4.1.2 same user agent it doesn't work and is off similar to the fiddle (they are all using the same stylesheet).

So basically 
Chrome: Yes.
Firefox: Yes.
Android Mobile 4.0.4: Yes.
Android Tablet 4.1.2: No.
Fiddle Chrome? No

Here's the complete code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="headTitle">
    <div id="headBtn">
        <div id="hBtn"></div>
    </div>
     <h1><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>">L'ART Magazine</a></h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    body {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height:1;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    /* has to be scroll, not auto */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
    div#hBtn {
        background:url('../images/icon_set.png') no-repeat -4px -53px;
        height:20px;
        width:20px;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        margin:auto;
    }
    div#headBtn {
        position:absolute;
        width:40px;
        height:40px;
        border-right:1px solid #999;
        cursor:hand;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    div#headTitle {
        height:40px;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#222;
        position:fixed;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
        z-index:1000;
    }
    div#headTitle a {
        color:red;
        line-height:40px;
        font-size:20px;
    }
```

So what's up SO?

Oh and here's an image too [image: http://i.imgur.com/EtwEKDl.png?1]

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having a similar problem on Android mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Give `margin: 0px;` for the `h1` tag

[Upadetd Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D6LtM/2/)

Comment: Interesting, that fixed the vertical center in fiddle but it's still not right on my Android tablet :/

Comment: @UzumakiDev can you give the provide screenshot of the device ?

Comment: @UzumakiDev just if the above shown was the problem just try giving margin: 0px !important;

Comment: ah I can't screen shot my device as it isn't supported or rooted.

Comment: I have a 7 inch galaxy tab where the problem is occurring but it works fine on a 4.3inch mobile on the same browser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48100/discussion-between-kawinesh-sk-and-uzumakidev)